# login/register working locally but not after deploying the project - laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

this is my first ever deployed project and it was working perfectly on my local machine but after the deployment the login and register isn't working anymore it just redirects me to the "check" function route without login in .

this is the check function in my controller that checks if the email and password are correct :

```
public function check(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8'
    ]);


    $userInfo = User::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();

    if (!$userInfo) {
        return back()->with('fail', 'adresse e-mail non reconnue');
    } else {
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $userInfo->password)) {
            $request->session()->put('LoggedUser', $userInfo->id);
            return redirect('/Dashboard');
        } else {
            return back()->with('fail', 'Mot de passe incorrect');
        }
    }
}
```

this is the route of the function :

```
Route::post('/check', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@check') ->name('check');
```

and this is the login  form even thou i don't think there's a problem with the form :

```
<form action=" {{ route('check')}} " method="post">
                @csrf

                @if(Session::get('fail'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
                     {{ Session::get('fail') }} 
                    </div>
                @endif
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        @error('email')
                      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
                     {{ $message }} 
                    </div> @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        @error('password')
                      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 
                     {{ $message }} 
                    </div> @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block" value="Se connecter">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

i tried clearing the cache and i tried changing the session driver option to cookies or database just to know if it can fix the problem .
i do not get any errors i just get redirected to the check function route " /check " and it says ' 419|page expired ' .

it might be an obvious problem that i do not know since it's my first time deploying a project, I'm on a shared hosting server and i used FTP to deploy the project .

everything else is working fine but the login and register .

**UPDATE 1**

i used the key:generate command and it didn't fix the problem .

**UPDATE 2**

this is my Dashboard method :

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $data = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>User::select('id','name','last_name')->where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedUser'))->first()];

    $list = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                     ->select(array('entreprises.RS as RS', 'entreprises.id as id' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as Tel1' , 'entreprises.Tel2 as Tel2' , 'entreprises.adresse as adresse' , 'entreprises.ville as ville' , 'entreprises.Fax as Fax' , 'entreprises.mail as mail' , 'entreprises.rubs as rubs' , 'entreprises.Siteweb as Siteweb' , 'entreprises.Descp as Descp' , 'entreprises.secteurs_id as secteurs_id' , 'entreprises.idact as idact' , 'entreprises.idSousCat as idSousCat' , 'entreprises.user_id as user_id' , 'entreprises.Logo as Logo'))
                     ->where('user_id' , '=' , session('LoggedUser') )
                     ->where('active' , '=' , 1)
                     ->paginate(10);  

                     $pending = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                     ->select(array('entreprises.RS as RS', 'entreprises.id as id' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as Tel1' , 'entreprises.Tel2 as Tel2' , 'entreprises.adresse as adresse' , 'entreprises.ville as ville' , 'entreprises.Fax as Fax' , 'entreprises.mail as mail' , 'entreprises.rubs as rubs' , 'entreprises.Siteweb as Siteweb' , 'entreprises.Descp as Descp' , 'entreprises.secteurs_id as secteurs_id' , 'entreprises.idact as idact' , 'entreprises.idSousCat as idSousCat' , 'entreprises.user_id as user_id' , 'entreprises.Logo as Logo'))
                     ->where('user_id' , '=' , session('LoggedUser') )
                     ->where('active' , '=' , 0)
                     ->paginate(10); 

                     $all = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                     ->select(array('entreprises.RS as RS', 'entreprises.id as id' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as Tel1' , 'entreprises.Tel2 as Tel2' , 'entreprises.adresse as adresse' , 'entreprises.ville as ville' , 'entreprises.Fax as Fax' , 'entreprises.mail as mail' , 'entreprises.rubs as rubs' , 'entreprises.Siteweb as Siteweb' , 'entreprises.Descp as Descp' , 'entreprises.secteurs_id as secteurs_id' , 'entreprises.idact as idact' , 'entreprises.idSousCat as idSousCat' , 'entreprises.user_id as user_id' , 'entreprises.Logo as Logo'))
                     ->where('user_id' , '=' , session('LoggedUser') )
                     ->paginate(10); 

    return view('Dashboard.dashboard' ,$data ,[ 'lists'=>$list , 'pendings'=> $pending , 'ALL'=>$all]);
}
```

and this is the dashboard route :

```
Route::get('/Dashboard','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

i fixed it by using the secure protocol "https", or you can change this in the session.php file :

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
```

to this :

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

and it will work on the http protocol too .

Comment: run php artisan key:generate

Comment: @JohnLobo can i ask what does it do ?

Comment: this will generate app key for applciation.try if its works or not

Comment: @JohnLobo i have to run the command and redeploy the project again, right !

Comment: you are using shared hosting so difficult to run command .so clear browser cache once and try

Comment: @JohnLobo it didn't work, maybe i need to redeploy  the project after i regenerated the key !!

Comment: you should generate key in server not in local

Comment: one think you can do is php artisan view:clear ,php artisan clear in local and then you can deploy

Comment: for using artisan command 
just make a route in web.php with a closure
then use Artisan facade
Artisan::call('key:generate');

Comment: and comment the validation part of your code
check if it happens again

Comment: @AmirDaneshkar the route doesn't work gives me the 402 error not found even thou i created a view for it

Comment: @AmirDaneshkar i tried to clear my cache using the route locally and it worked but i can't seem to do it on the live server

Comment: ill user answer section

Comment: does other routes work?
the ones that does not need authentication ?
have you changed the permission of files and folders from you hosting's  panel?

Comment: @AmirDaneshkar all of the other routes are working fine, i didn't change anything i just deployed it normally

Comment: @AmirDaneshkar can you please check the error i told you about !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible fixes :

1. check if the the csrf is present on the form
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. Laravel file and folder permissions
4. Laravel session setting
5. check the form to see if there is `@csrf`  present in form
6. Clear the cache of app and generate a new key.

In the shared hosting you need to use `\Artisan::call(command:com)` in a controller or in **web.php** inside a closure

```
php artisan cache:clear
    
php artisan config:clear
    
php artisan config:cache

php artisan key:generate
```

3.change the permission of storage and vendor folders,
also the bootstrap/cache.

Their permissions should be (755 :storage & vendor) and (644 : bootstrap/caches)

```
chmod -R 755 storage

chmod -R 755 vendor

chmod -R 644 bootstrap/caches
```

4. check the app/config/session.php

```
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', <your domain>),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), // in case of cookie
```

### ***After each on these its better to clear the cache and config !!!***

### ***Clear browser cache or try with another one !!!***

Comment: now i get this error " Your serialized closure might have been modified and it's unsafe to be unserialized. Make sure you use the same security provider, with the same settings, both for serialization and unserialization. " any idea why ?

Comment: well it worked i deleted the route.php in the cache folder and the routes worked and i generated the key, but that didn't fix the problem of the login

Comment: i copied the key and it didn't fix the problem, i don't think the key is the problem because i generated one in the live server already

Comment: maybe the problem is the redirect i am using in my controller function

Comment: where do i add this ?

Comment: i updated the question, and i add the dd($request->all()); to the check function, it worked locally and returned the inputs data but it didn't work at all on the live server it returned the 419 expired error

Comment: this probably means that you have problem with your APP_KEY.
then check the .env file and be sure that the session part is filled
use the ``Artisan::call('config:clear')`` and ``Artisan::call('config:cache')``

Comment: no changing the redirect didn't fix it either

Comment: by the way i deleted the config.php from the cache folder is that the problem !

Comment: i dont know if it is relevent, but you can always try restoring it and then checking if the solutions work

Comment: i tried clearing the config it didn't work either, and what do you mean restoring it ?

Comment: take it from local and add it there. have you read the update that i added to answer?

Comment: i tried what you said in the answer it didn't work

Comment: can you share the hosting url>

Comment: i checked the laravel.log but i didn't understand it, i will share the URL for my project if that's gonna help

Comment: i updated the answer, this is all I can think of, hope that it solves yur problem, also try clearing browser cache

Comment: i will try everything you pointed at and hope it works, thank you so much i will let you know if something worked

Comment: i fixed, the problem is the session .
i was using secure in the session secure cookie while using only http when i changed it to false it worked, and it worked before i even change it when i used https in my URL .

Answer (score 0):

The following commands work for me:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan key:generate
```